# Is throwing a temporary value as reference undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, exception, reference, temporary-objects

To my surprise, `std::runtime_error` only has a `const std::string&` constructor, but no value constructor. Thus I am wondering if `throw std::runtime_error("Temporary" + std::to_string(100));` is defined. After all we are creating an exception object that refers to a temporary object inside the scope of a function that immediately exits (as we throw out of it). Further investigation showed that while returning a constant reference to a temporary value immediately causes a segfault on my system, throwing one doesn't:

```
const std::string& undefined_behavior() {
    return "Undefined " + std::to_string(1);
}

void test() {
    throw std::runtime_error("Hello : " + std::to_string(2));   
}

void test2() {
    const std::string& ref = "Hello : " + std::to_string(3); 
    throw ref;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //std::cout << undefined_behavior() << std::endl;
    try {
        test(); 
    } catch(const std::runtime_error& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    try {
        test2();
    } catch(const std::string& ref) {
        std::cout << ref << std::endl;
    }
}
```

On my system, `undefined_behavior()` crashes immediately but `test()` and `test2()` run fine.

While I know the call to `undefined_behavior()` is undefined behavior, is `test()` and `test2()` undefined? If not, do thrown values get a specfied treatment?

And if they are all undefined but happened to work on my computer by accident, what is the proper way to throw an exception with a variable message?

Comment: `std::runtime_error("Temporary" + std::to_string(100));` -- This object is fully constructed *before* the `throw` happens.  Thus there is no issue throwing the `std::runtime_error` instance.

Comment: Somewhat related, things get more spicy with [std::rethrow_exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_exception), [std::current_exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception), [std::exception_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr), and threading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `const std::string&` constructor doesn't cause the exception object to store a reference to the passed `std::string`. `std::runtime_error` will make an internal copy of the passed string (although the copy will be stored in an usual way, probably reference-counted in an allocation external to the exception object; this is to give better exception guarantees when the exception object is copied, which the standard requires).

A function taking a `const` lvalue reference doesn't usually mean that it takes ownership or stores a reference to the object.

Prior to C++11 there was no reason to not use a `const` reference here, since it was always more efficient than passing by-value. With C++11 move semantics that changed and it is true that usually these kind of constructors had rvalue reference variants added with C++11, so that passing a temporary `std::string` object to the constructor would allow more efficient move-construction instead of copy-construction.

My guess is that this simply never was done for the exception classes because the performance of their construction should not be important in comparison to the overhead of actually throwing the exception.

So in `test()`'s case a temporary `string` object is created from the `+` operation, which is passed to the constructor and the exception object will make a copy of it. After the initialization of the exception object the temporary string is destroyed, but that is not a problem, since the exception object stores/references a copy.

In `test2()` the same would apply if you had written `throw std::runtime_error(ref)`. However, here a reference is bound immediately to the temporary object materialized from the return value of `+`. This causes its lifetime to be extended to that of the reference variable. Therefore again, the temporary lives long enough for the `std::runtime_error` to make a copy from it.

But since you write simply `throw ref` that is not exactly what happens. `throw ref` will throw a `std::string`, because that is the type of the `ref` expression. However, `throw` doesn't actually use the object referenced by the expression as exception object. The exception object is *initialized* from the operand of the `throw` expression. So here, the exception object will be another `std::string` object (in unspecified storage) which will be initialized from the temporary that `ref` refers to.

`undefined_behavior()` has undefined behavior when the return value is used, because the temporary `std::string` object materialized from the `+` return value and which the return value of `undefined_behavior()` references is *not* lifetime-extended. Although it is again immediately bound by a reference, the lifetime-extension rule specifically doesn't apply to objects bound to a reference in a return value initialization. Instead the temporary is destroyed when the function returns, causing the function to always return a dangling reference.

Comment: One other followup:  Because the `std::runtime_error` copy constructor is marked as noexcept, it will likely always copy the string into some other internal storage.

Comment: In `test2()` there is actually no `std::runtime_error` object involved.

Comment: @JakobStark Oh right. I completely didn't notice. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Great answer thanks! Can I make use of this "unspecified storage" like: `const std::string& test_lifetime_extension() { try { throw "Hello " + std::to_string(40); } catch(const std::string& ref) { return ref; } }

int main(int argc, char** argv) { std::cout << test_lifetime_extension() << std::endl; }` Is this undefined?

Comment: @Winter No, the exception object is destroyed at the end of the `catch` handler if it isn't rethrown. `test_lifetime_extension` still returns a dangling reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is not undefined behavior.

---

In `test1()`, the constructor of `std::runtime_error` makes an internal copy. There is even a note on this at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error):

> Because copying `std::runtime_error` is not permitted to throw
> exceptions, this message is typically stored internally as a
> separately-allocated reference-counted string. This is also why
> there is no constructor taking `std::string&&`: it would have to
> copy the content anyway.

---

In `test2()` there is no `std::runtime_error` involved. Instead, as you can read e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw), in the following statement

```
throw expr;
```

the *exception object* is copy-initialized from `expr`. So there is a copy made of that temporary string also in this case.